# What Happened To The Acceptance Rate Display?

Tags: discussion

Why are questions no longer displaying the acceptance rate of a user?

I answered a question then looked at the user's profile and realized his acceptance rate was roughly less than 20%...

Probably wouldn't have answered ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that the other day too. The official explanation is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/209390) and a discussion of a possible replacement [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165179/209390).

About the removal (From Kevin Montrose):

> Starting with the next build accept rate will no longer be shown.
>
> We're still keeping track of it on the backend for various things, but the negative behavior its display encourages outweighs its benefits.

Comment: Which annoys me a tiny bit because the accept rate helps motivate people to actually follow through on their questions, but I do understand their reasoning and I like the "citizenship level" idea as a replacement.

Comment: You can still comment on the question... IMO that works better as an attempt to motivate someone to accept more answers.

Comment: "The system should be there to remember people to accept answer, but as now is used by people to decide if they should ignore a question."  --> quote from my answer there. That score only existed to make people ignore post.

Comment: @KitMenke, I tell people to accept more, but then I feel like I'm crossing the line and may come off as being rude. When is it kosher and when is it not?

Comment: @rjcup3 If you notice they have a bunch of questions with answers that should be accepted go ahead and leave a comment. "Hey [name], I noticed you have a bunch of questions without an accepted answer. Just a friendly reminder to be sure to accept the answers that have solved your problem. It helps future visitors who have the same question."

Comment: @rjcup3 Speaking of accept rates ;) did I answer your question? I know what you mean about feeling like it's rude to ask, but this community does have a way of inspiring participation.